# Rescaling layer destroys model performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, layer

I am having an issue using a rescaling layer in tensorflow. My images are scaled from 0-255, and I would like to rescale them to -1,1. My model trains fine without a rescaling layer, and I would think that adding one would be helpful. However, when I add this layer, my model no longer improves with training.

Here's my code:

```
    scale_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1 / 127.5, offset=-1)

    #creates new model with fully connected head 
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,3), name='Input')
    x = scale_layer(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Resizing(input_size, input_size)(x)
    x = transfer_model(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
        
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

As stated, the model trains fine if I comment out the rescaling layer, etc. Why would this be? Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen but can you try this:

```
#creates new model with fully connected head 
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,3), name='Input')
x = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1 / 127.5, input_shape=(28,28,3), offset=-1)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Resizing(input_size, input_size)(x)
x = transfer_model(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

There are 2 ways to perform rescaling You can apply it to the dataset by calling Dataset.map or you can include the layer inside your model definition

Comment: Thanks for the input. Making the suggested change didn't seem to help. I ended up rescaling as a separate preparative step. I remain curious.